# pgfplots nodes near coords with error bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am working on a horizontal bar plot with error bars. In addition I'd like to place the actual value of each bar with `nodes near coords` in the plot. However they tend to overlap with the positive error bar. In some cases this is easy to fix with `nodes near coords style={xshift=32pt}`. However that only makes sense if the error bars are roughly within the same range. Is there any way to tie the node to the positive error bar's end?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, BCOR=4mm, fontsize=12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xbar, bar width=0.7cm, width=0.7\textwidth,
                xmin=0, xmax=7, enlarge y limits = {abs = .8},
                xmajorgrids=true, xminorgrids=true,
                major y tick style={draw=none}, minor x tick num=1,
                minor grid style={dashed},
                ytick={-1,-2}, 
                yticklabels={A,B},
                yticklabel style={align=right},
                nodes near coords, nodes near coords style={xshift=32pt},
                legend style={cells={anchor=west},at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north}, legend reversed,
                ]
                
\addplot [fill=red!30, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
        (4.5,-1) +- (1.197,0)
        (3.88,-2) +- (0.995,0)
    };
    
\addplot [fill=green!30, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
        (5.4,-1) +- (0.7,0)
        (4.2,-2) +- (1.508,0)
    };
    
\addplot [fill=yellow!30, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] coordinates {
        (5.4,-1) +- (0.57,0)
        (4.21,-2) +- (0.833,0)
    };
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course this is possible ;) Will you be able to adapt the solution given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485859/95441 yourself to your needs? If you should fail, ping me and I'll write an answer here.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I get the concept but I don't know how to access the error bar value without table input. `visualization depends on={<x error> \as \offset}, node near coords style={shift={(axis direction cs:0,\offset)}},`

Comment: This should work for inline tables as well (without having tested it). So transform your `coordinates` to `table`, remove the brackets and the `+-` in the "data" body and give appropriate table headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, thanks a lot to Stefan, it actually works with inline tables! Here ist the solution:

The key properties are:

```
visualization depends on={\thisrow{error} \as \offset},
node near coords style={shift={(axis direction cs:\offset,0)}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xbar, bar width=0.7cm, width=0.7\textwidth,
                xmin=0, xmax=7, enlarge y limits = {abs = .8},
                xmajorgrids=true, xminorgrids=true,
                major y tick style={draw=none}, minor x tick num=1,
                minor grid style={dashed},
                ytick={-1,-2}, 
                yticklabels={A,B},
                yticklabel style={align=right},
                nodes near coords,
                visualization depends on={\thisrow{error} \as \offset},
                node near coords style={shift={(axis direction cs:\offset,0)}}
                ]
                
\addplot [fill=red!30, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] table [x=value, y=position, x error=error] {
        value   position    error
        4.5     -1          1.197
        3.88    -2          0.995
    };
    
\addplot [fill=green!30, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] table [x=value, y=position, x error=error] {
        value   position    error
        5.4     -1          0.7
        4.2     -2          1.508
    };
    
\addplot [fill=yellow!30, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] table [x=value, y=position, x error=error] {
        value   position    error
        5.4     -1          0.57
        4.21    -2          0.833
    };
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]